# How to verify the game version?

Tags: pc, dont-starve

I'm not sure if [the GOG version](https://www.gog.com/game/dont_starve) is up to date as GOG Galaxy displays an seemingly older `20171215` build being installed. Developers  generally prioritize Steam and GOG versions of games may not receive minor patches and the updates may arrive months late — or not at all.

[image: GOG Galaxy]

Is it possible to verify the version in the game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hit backspace on the main screen, it'll show the rev-version on the left.

The version also shows on the "mod at your own risk" warning when loading the game with mods active.

[image]